# Unable to install Canon PIXMA MG2520 printer in Ubuntu 12.04 (32 bit)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, canon

I have an old pc (HP Pavilion a1203w with an AMD Sempron) that used to run Windows XP. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 a while back & haven't had any problems until I got this new printer.

I went to Canons website & they don't seem to have the driver I need. I found some drivers on other websites & downloaded them but they don't appear on the list of drivers when I try to install the printer.

I'm new at this stuff, so I'd like to avoid using the terminal if I can. I'm a bit nervous about getting under the hood (although I will if I have to). I don't want to do more harm than good.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The Pixma MG2520 is covered in newer Ubuntu versions; for instance 15.04. I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: I already tried the upgrade without success. It seems that the only way I'd be able to get a newer version of Ubuntu is to get a new pc.

Answer (score 0):

The Canon Europe website has Linux drivers for the MG2500 series [here](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg2540.aspx?type=drivers&language=&os=Linux%20%2832-bit%29).  Scroll down for the .deb versions.

(I linked to the 32 bit version, if yours is 64 bit just use the dropdown box menu to change it).

Once you have downloaded the cnjifilter....deb.tar.gz file, open your file manager and locate the file. Right-click it and select "Extract Here".  When this process finishes, you will have folder with the same name as the file you downloaded except it will end in "deb".  Doubleclick that folder to open it.

Inside the folder will be two folders and a file called `install.sh`.  Right-click the file and select Properties.  Click on the Permissions tab in the window that opens.  If the box labeled Execute is not ticked, tick it.  Then select Close in this window.

Now open a terminal window by typing `Cntrl-Alt-T` simultaneously.  Then type

`cd ~/Downloads/cnijfilter-mg2500series-4.00-1-deb/`

(if the folder name is different, substitute what your folder is called)

Now type

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

A prompt will appear and ask for your password.  When you type it in, you will not see any feedback, not even the cursor moving.  Press `enter` after typing your password.

Now the install script will start.  I cannot run it on my computer so I do not know exactly what it will ask, but hopefully it will be intuitive.

Let me know in the comments if you encounter any difficulties with this.

Comment: I downloaded the driver (thanks for the info, btw) but I've no idea how to install it since my pc doesn't automatically recognize it. Like I said, I'm new to this stuff & if it isn't plug & play like Windows, I'm lost. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll update my answer above to add the steps.